# React build run on server using pm2 in windows

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, npm, pm2

React.js or Angular.js app works fine if I run `npm run serve`, But when I try to run serve using pm2, Its throwing error in Windows, while its working fine in Ubuntu.

I tried to connect to run serve using pm2:

```
pm2 start npm --name="UI" -- run serve
```

It throws error:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\deepak.chaudhary\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:29:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
```

Comment: try creating a file with the command `echo "npm run serve" >> serve.js` and then use `pm2 start serve.js --name="UI"`

Comment: It throws error : 

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { npm run serve
                                                                  ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: Try `pm2 start "npm run serve" --name="UI"

Answer (score 4):

you can run

`npm run build` (to create a build folder)

`pm2 serve build 5000 --spa` (from the root project folder)

for me it works

Answer (score 1):

Use `pm2 start "npm run serve" --name="UI"`

Comment: Got something new in the log:

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, uv_pipe_open
    at Object.exports._forkChild (child_process.js:110:5)
    at Object.setupChannel (internal/process.js:247:8)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:63:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
App [UI:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
App [UI:0] starting in -fork mode-
App [UI:0] online
child_process.js:110
  p.open(fd);

Comment: After some googling got this `When using windows to start node with pm2, use cluster_mode to start, you can successfully start the node service.
The command is as follows: pm2 start index.js -i 0 -f Start the node service in cluster mode`

Answer (score 0):

Please try alternative service startup agent like Forever, supervisor, etc

Here is the command for Forever to start your apps.

```
forever start node_modules/.bin/babel-node tools/distServer.js
```

Let me know if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the port that you want to use and start the application though PM2 / React Scripts directly:

```
export PORT=4000 && pm2 start node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js --name "application"
```